# Cocoa app scrolling slow when window on focus, fast when not

Tags: macos, cocoa

I have a cocoa app with a window containing an NSTableView.  Each row has a few columns, three radio boxes and two buttons.  Currently the table has 260 rows and when the window is focused the scrolling in the table view is atrociously slow and jittery.  When the window is not focused and I mouse over the table view and scroll it's buttery smooth.

I've tried to solve the slow performance by changing the background drawing and enabling CoreAnimation Layer to no avail.

Why would the scrolling be fast when the window isn't focused but slow when it is?

I'm just baffled as to why the scrolling is so darn slow.

Here's my ProposalTableViewController.h

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <QuickLook/QuickLook.h>
#import <Quartz/Quartz.h>

@interface ProposalTableViewController : NSObject<NSTableViewDataSource, NSTableViewDelegate, QLPreviewPanelDelegate, QLPreviewPanelDataSource>{
@public
    NSMutableArray *list;
    IBOutlet NSTableView *tableView;
    IBOutlet NSSearchField *searchText;
    IBOutlet NSTextField *countTextField;
}

@property (strong) QLPreviewPanel *previewPanel;

+ (ProposalTableViewController *)getInstance;

- (IBAction)deleteRow:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)exportData:(id)sender;
- (void)loadData;
- (void)countItems;

@end
```

And my ProposalTableViewController.m

```
#import "ProposalTableViewController.h"
#import "Proposal.h"
#import "StatusRadioView.h"
#import "DBManager.h"
#import "filePathButtonView.h"
#import <Quartz/Quartz.h>
#import "AppDelegate.h"
@implementation Proposal (QLPreviewItem)

- (NSURL *)previewItemURL
{
    return [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.pdf",self.filePath]];
}

- (NSString *)previewItemTitle
{
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Proposal %@",self.proposalNumber];
}

@end

@implementation ProposalTableViewController

static ProposalTableViewController *instance;
+ (ProposalTableViewController *)getInstance{
    return instance;
}

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//                                                      Init
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
- (id)init{
    self = [super init];
    if(self){
        instance = self;

        list = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        [self loadData];

        for (NSTableColumn *tableColumn in tableView.tableColumns ) {
            NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:tableColumn.identifier ascending:YES selector:@selector(compare:)];
            [tableColumn setSortDescriptorPrototype:sortDescriptor];
        }
    }
    return self;
}
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//                                                      Load Data from SQLite
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
- (void)loadData {
    list = [[DBManager getProposalTable] select:@""];
    NSSortDescriptor* desc = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"proposalNumber" ascending:NO selector:@selector(compare:)];
    [list sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:desc, nil]];
    [tableView reloadData];
    [self countItems: list];
}
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//                                                      Number of Rows in Table View
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
- (NSInteger) numberOfRowsInTableView:(NSTableView *)tableView {
    return [list count];
}

-(void)countItems:(NSArray *)list; {
    NSString *countText;
    int size = [list count];
    if (size == 1){
        countText = @"item in list";
    }else{
        countText = @"items in list";
    }
    NSString *itemCount = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d %@", size, countText];
    [countTextField setStringValue:itemCount];
}
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//                                                      Get View for Table Column
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
- (NSView *)tableView:(NSTableView *)table_view viewForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row {
    Proposal *p = [list objectAtIndex:row];
    NSString *identifier = [tableColumn identifier];
    NSString *holdingValue;

    NSTableCellView *cell = [table_view makeViewWithIdentifier:identifier owner:self];
    if([identifier isEqualToString:@"status"]){
        StatusRadioView *radioView = [[StatusRadioView alloc] initWithProposal:p];
        return radioView;
    }else if ([identifier isEqualToString:@"filePath"]){
        filePathButtonView *buttonView = [[filePathButtonView alloc]initWithProposal:p];
        return buttonView;
    }else if ([identifier isEqualToString:@"clientAccessPoint"]){
        holdingValue = [p valueForKey:identifier];
            if (!holdingValue){
                cell.textField.stringValue = @"N/A";
            }else{
                cell.textField.stringValue = [p valueForKey:identifier];
            }
    }else{
    cell.textField.stringValue = [p valueForKey:identifier];
    }
    return cell;
}

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//                                                      Sort Descriptors did Change
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-(void)tableView:(NSTableView *)mtableView sortDescriptorsDidChange:(NSArray *)oldDescriptors {
    [list sortUsingDescriptors: [mtableView sortDescriptors]];
    [tableView reloadData];
}
//table row height
-(CGFloat)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView heightOfRow:(NSInteger)row {
    return 25;
}
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//                                                      Search Text did Change
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
- (void)controlTextDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification {
    NSSortDescriptor* desc = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"proposalNumber" ascending:NO selector:@selector(compare:)];
    NSTextField *textField = [notification object];
    NSString *str = [textField stringValue];
    list = [[DBManager getProposalTable] select:str];
    [list sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:desc, nil]];
    [tableView reloadData];
    [self countItems: list];
}
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//                                                      Export DATA
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
- (IBAction)exportData:(id)sender{
    NSString *content = @"";
    for(Proposal *p in list){
        NSString *row = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,%@,%@,%@,%@,%@,%@,%@,%@,%@", p.proposalNumber,p.itemNumber,p.clientName,p.medium,p.support,p.cost,p.dateCreated,p.status,p.dateStatusChanged,p.clientAccessPoint];
        row = [row stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@""];
        row = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n", row];
        content = [content stringByAppendingString:row];
    }
    //get the documents directory:
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Baumgartner Fine Art Restoration"];
    NSString *fileName = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"proposalBuilderDatabase.csv"];

    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory
                              withIntermediateDirectories:NO
                                               attributes:nil
                                                    error:nil];
    [content writeToFile:fileName
              atomically:NO
                encoding:NSStringEncodingConversionAllowLossy
                   error:nil];

    NSAlert *alert = [[NSAlert alloc] init];
    [alert setMessageText:@"Export Succeeded"];
    [alert addButtonWithTitle:@"Ok"];
    [alert runModal];
}
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//                                                      Delete row from DB and table
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
- (IBAction)deleteRow:(id)sender{
    NSString *row = list[tableView.selectedRow];
    NSString *mid = [row valueForKey:@"m_id"];

    ProposalTable *deleteRow = [[ProposalTable alloc] init];

    [deleteRow deleteWithId: mid];
    [self loadData];
    [tableView reloadData];
}
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//                                                      QuickLook
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
- (NSInteger)numberOfPreviewItemsInPreviewPanel:(QLPreviewPanel *)panel {
    return [list count];
}

- (id <QLPreviewItem>)previewPanel:(QLPreviewPanel *)panel previewItemAtIndex:(NSInteger)index {
    return list[tableView.selectedRow];
}

- (BOOL)previewPanel:(QLPreviewPanel *)panel handleEvent:(NSEvent *)event {
    // redirect all key down events to the table view
    if ([event type] == NSKeyDown) {
        [tableView keyDown:event];
        return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}

// This delegate method provides the rect on screen from which the panel will zoom.
- (NSRect)previewPanel:(QLPreviewPanel *)panel sourceFrameOnScreenForPreviewItem:(id <QLPreviewItem>)item {
    return NSZeroRect;
}

- (BOOL)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView shouldSelectRow:(NSInteger)rowIndex {
    [[QLPreviewPanel sharedPreviewPanel]reloadData];
    return YES;
}
@end
```

Here's my ProposalTableView.h

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface ProposalTableView : NSTableView

@end
```

And my ProposalTableView.m

```
#import "ProposalTableView.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"
@implementation ProposalTableView

- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect {
    [super drawRect:dirtyRect];
    self.wantsLayer = YES;

    // Drawing code here.
}


- (void)keyDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent
{
    NSString *key = [theEvent charactersIgnoringModifiers];
    if ([key isEqual:@" "])
    {
        [[NSApp delegate] togglePreviewPanel:self];
    }
    else
    {
        [super keyDown:theEvent];
    }
}
@end
```

There's also code that establishes the SqLite DB connection and interacts with the DB to get the records or delete etc... but that's not really needed here...  I also have code that draws the radio buttons and the other buttons but again, I don't think that's necessary unless someone thinks that the drawing is creating the slowdown...?

Comment: Can you show us some code? Do you use `NSScrollViewDelegate` methods? Please provide your controller code.

Comment: @Astoria `NSScrollView` doesn't have a delegate.

Comment: @Willeke you're right, it doesn't. I meant some callback method for `NSViewBoundsDidChangeNotification`-notification.

Comment: Edited to add some code... thanks for looking!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out that the drawing of the radio buttons is what is causing the slowdown... back to the drawing board.